# Block a select JS file from loading

Tags: javascript, request, ads

I wish to block a specific .js file from loading on my website.
The .js file I wish to block (Let's call it blockme.js) is being loaded by a different .js file (Lets call this one script.js). I cannot edit "script.js" as it is hosted elsewhere, but I do want it to run on my site (So removing it is not an option). "blockme.js" is currently being blocked by the Brave browser, but I would like it to be blocked by all browsers (Hense the reason I want it removed). If there is a way to prevent the HTTP request from being made (Or at least a way to prevent the code from being executed), that would be awesome.

Note: "script.js" provides additional functionality to my site, however "blockme.js" is an ad-script contained within this added functionality that I want removed.

(Let me know if I didn't explain this well, I did the best I could)

EDIT: I am going to add in here that the "script.js" is actually Google's programable search (cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx), and "blockme.js" is actually cse.google.com/adsense/search/async-ads.js

Comment: I mean, this is slightly outside the scope of the question as you've asked it, but I would make a concerted effort to **avoid, at all costs** any library or other JavaScript include that inserted arbitrary ads into the site including it - this is **not** typical and **not at all** generally accepted/good practice by whomever has developed the file you're including. Not only would I do this out of principle, but for the fact that inclusion of additional files opens more points of failure and more attack vectors for malicious actors to eventually exploit.

Comment: It seems weird to me that you cannot edit the script "script.js". Your webpage must fetch it one way or another, therefore you must be able to fetch it yourself and edit it then.

Comment: I guess I should have added that the script in question is the one for Google's Programable Search. @Doreapp, I don't think I am allowed to self-host that, am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am understanding this correctly so I will do my best to offer a few solutions.

## Option 1

As stated in the comments, if it is your website and you are adding the "parent" script, the obvious answer is to edit the script.

As you have updated your question to mention it is a Google Programmable Search script. You could download the script and make your edits.

Take a look at the below code taken from the [Programmable Search Docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox)  "try it" button.

```html
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=000888210889775888983:pqb3ch1ewhg"></script>

<div class="gcse-searchbox-only" data-resultsUrl="https://googlecustomsearch.appspot.com/elementv2/two-page_results_elements_v2.html?query=test"></div>
```

You could simply grab the `src` url and download it.

*Note: this is just an example URL, use your own.*

Make your edits and save it with any name of your choosing. I would recommend something descriptive. You are now not only editing the parts you don't want but are hosting the script which has some pros/cons:

- Pros: It will give you greater control (edit it), faster loads (you host it)
- Cons: Google may change something and you will need to get the latest version, etc

## Option 2

If you are looking to edit this because the "Free" version of the script triggers ads, you may consider the other [Programmable Search Engine Offerings](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview#summary_of_programmable_search_engine_offerings). Unless this is a big site you are building then the costs will be minimal and if it is a large site I assume the budget will be available.
Again, I do not know the context of the problem you are solving and its outside the context of this question.

## Option 3

Again without knowing more, it is hard to cover all scenarios but if you are building something to block ads there are many options and libraries.

Here is an [example of an adblocker](https://github.com/cliqz-oss/adblocker) that integrates in a few environments.

Comment: Although this did not directly solve the issue, it did give me an idea that did. Thanks!